# how to make sure remote host treat ctrl-h NOT as backspace in putty sessions?

Tags: ssh, putty

I have problem enabling `ctrl-h` as a shortcut (for tmux and vim) from putty to linux remote hosts. To be precise, I think `ctrl-h` is indeed sent. To confirm, when I type `ctrl-v`, `ctrl-h` I got `^H`. (Backspace does work as ^? since I'm already doing `stty erase ^?`.)

However, in the terminal, `ctrl-h` is still interpreted as backspace.

Dose anybody aware of the issue and the fix to free up `ctrl-h` from backspace?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal program you use determines the code sent for a backspace, either ^H or ^? (DEL) typically. Its value is set in its settings or preferences, usually in a tab or dropdown mentioning keyboard, but every terminal program has its own way of defining it.

tmux has a config value, `backspace  key`, where `key` could be `^?`. Note that tmux is run within your terminal program.

When you ssh to a machine, a TERM environment variable is set with what the machine thinks is your terminal, which defines what capabilities or keycodes to use to perform things like move to the right or left or up or down. Backspace is one of them, and to see its value enter `tput kbs | cat -v`. This could still be different from your tmux setting.

Mixing these settings is not a good idea, and ^H is a backspace in the ascii definition. Forcing a setting isn't usually necessary and could cause issues from someone else who isn't using your settings to ssh into the same machine.

Comment: Trying to understand this. Is this to say it is impossible to send true ctrl+h throughput putty?